# How to resolve the mysql error access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, mysql-workbench

for several days I have had a problem that I cannot solve.

the problem is that when i want to create a database or use mysql in general the following error is displayed "access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: YES)" and it happens since I have installed mariadb on my pc.

here is the picture of the error I get:

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

after that i decided to delete mariadb from my pc, i even checked if mariadb still exists on my pc go to the c directory to check, and also in the search bar when i search for mariadb no results displays, normally mariadb is deleted but I doubt that its service is hidden somewhere and that it is active since the error is still there so I can't find another explanation.

I tried to follow some solutions that I found on the internet like this one for example:

[image: img_1]

but when i apply this solution on mysql shell i get the following error:

[image: img_2]

suddenly I searched the internet again and I found that you have to put a \sql before putting the request.

but when I put this and I re-execute my request I receive a new error which is:

> error : not connected

as you can see in this picture :

[image: img_3]

I searched the internet to solve this problem and what I found was that you had to put a `\connect root@localhost`

but when i do this the access denied error come back again

as you can see in this picture:

[image: img_5]

I also tested several solutions but nothing works for me, so I count on you to help me :(

so can someone help me please ????

Comment: Did you put a password on the MySQL root account?

Comment: try local host and changing to native password, is not necessary

Comment: yes i had put a password